# com_error function not in pythoncom

Tags: python, win32com, pythoncom

I am working on a project in which we link Aspen Plus to Python, so we can apply a reinforcement learning agent to design and optimize a separation train. Meanwhile a lot of errors have been fixed, but currently I am stuc on the following error:
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (1, 'Aspen.Unknown', 'No message available', None, 0, 0), None)

I tried to use a try and except statement to intercept this error, but com_errors are not interceptable in regular except statements.
Online I found solutions which use the following statement:

```
try:
   ...
except pythoncom.com_error:
...
```

This statement does not seem to work for me, since I get a warning:
Cannot find reference 'com_error' in 'pythoncom.py'

Does anyone has an idea to solve this?
Help is much appreciated!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FhWQ.png)

Comment: I have read somewhere that `pythoncom` now turn to `pywin32`